# How to add default logout button of sharepoint online functionality in sharepoint hosted addin

Tags: sharepoint-online

i am trying to use sharepoint default logout functionality, but i m not able access logout button in sharepoint hosted addin, is there any way to use microsoft logout

Answer (score 0):

Every user can see their sign out option on the ribbon or under the profile photo, but i am not sure why you can't see the default sign out option.

for sign out your page you can use the following URL pattern
**https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/signout.aspx** - this URL will kick you out from the sharepoint page